# How do I pass a value from one mobile screen to another using Acumatica MDSL?

Tags: acumatica, mobile-application

Here is the scenario:
I have a GI ListFolder, (DB-Appointments), which displays Tech Appoints and the RefNbr of those appointments on the mobile app.
I want to have the user tap on an SO number and then be able to send that SO number to customized mobile app (Service Orders) which will allow the user to edit and change the service order information.
HOWEVER, I am unable to determine how to pass the value of the RefNbr from the first mobile app screen to the other one using the "redirect" command inside of the "EditDetail" container action. (code below)

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
  add container "Result" {
    containerActionsToExpand = 2
    add field "ServiceOrderTypeFSServiceOrderSrvOrdType"
    add field "RefNbr"
    add containerAction "Insert" {
      icon = "system://Plus"
      behavior = Create
      redirect = True
    }
    add containerAction "EditDetail" {
      behavior = Open
      redirect = True
      redirectToScreen = "GI993132"
      redirectToContainer = "Filter_$List$ServiceOrderTypeFSServiceOrderRefNbr"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it has been a couple of weeks without an answer, I can offer an alternative approach.

I haven't done redirects to other fields in the GI, but I do something similar to what you are describing.  If you are open to alternatives, you can use the GI to go to a screen for the record (i.e. the Appointment).  Then create a screen in the mobile app for the Service Order.  Then put an action on the Appointment graph to *View Service Order*.  Finally, on the Appointment screen use a RecordAction to redirect via the View Service Order action.

```
add recordAction "ViewServiceOrder" {
  redirect = True
}
```

In this way, the redirect is defined as an action within Acumatica, and you are simply executing that action.